# django-session-security session not expiring

Tags: python, django

i am trying to use ajax pooling on my site (setTimeout) alongside django-session-security . In the documentation there is a mention of `SESSION_SECURITY_PASSIVE_URL` but i can't seem to get it to work.

My settings:

```
SESSION_SECURITY_WARN_AFTER = 15
SESSION_SECURITY_EXPIRE_AFTER = 21
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_SECURITY_PASSIVE_URL = ['http://localhost:8000/core/notice/check/', 'core/notice/check/', '/core/notice/check/']
```

My javascript:

```
  setTimeout(function(){
    get_notifications();
  }, 2000);
```

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please specify, what exactly do you mean by saying that you can't get it to work? Do your users never get logged out automatically?

Comment: @IgorGai yes, they never get logged out. `SESSION_SECURITY_PASSIVE_URL` should be working but for some reason its not

Comment: And have you carefully gone through all the steps from [the documentation](http://django-session-security.readthedocs.org/en/stable-2.x.x/quick.html) ?

Comment: @IgorGai yes because if i remove the `setTimeout` everything works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it's just because your settings parameter name is missing the ending 's'. It should be 'SESSION_SECURITY_PASSIVE_URL**S**' instead of 'SESSION_SECURITY_PASSIVE_URL' in your case. Consider the source code [here](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-session-security/blob/stable/2.x.x/session_security/settings.py#L35).

Other than that I believe you can safely remove redundant elements from the SESSION_SECURITY_PASSIVE_URLS list and leave just the *'/core/notice/check/'* entry there. Again, as we can see from [the source code](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-session-security/blob/stable/2.x.x/session_security/middleware.py#L30) the decision of whether request 'is passive' is made by checking the *request.path* against the list of values from the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, thus attempting to answer here. Have you added `{% include 'session_security/all.html' %}` to your (base) template? Also do you have added `session_security` URLs in appropriate `urls.py` file?

Comment: yes i have all that otherwise it wouldn't even work when i remove the `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

`SESSION_SECURITY_PASSIVE_URLS` allows you to add static urls.  However, most urls in Django are anything but static.  How would you add dynamic urls to this list to bypass session update.  For example in url `/category/1/product/5/`, 1 and 5 are dynamic ids but I would like to skip any url that matches the pattern

```
'/category/(?P<cat_id>[\d]+)/product/(?P<product_id>[\d]+)/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely, but if you are using **django-ajax** middleware **AJAXMiddleware**, it **conflicts** with session_security mechanism, and either the session expiry notification might not appear or session expiration might not work altogether. I had to remove AJAXMiddleware to make session_security work again.